# How to filter Scala Spark DataFrame if row matches ID in another DataFrame and timestamp is below the other frames timestamp

Tags: scala, apache-spark, data-science

I want to filter out entries in a DataFrame of message events based on when they were edited. I have a DataFrame that has the message events, and another DataFrame that represents when/if they were edited. The deletion should delete rows in the message table if they have a matching index in the edited table AND if the timestamp in the message table is below the corresponding edit event.

The Edited DataFrame is:

```
+----------+-------------------+
| timestamp|index              |
+----------+-------------------+
|1556247980|                 78|
|1558144430|                 87|
|1549964820|                 99|
+----------+-------------------+
```

The Message DataFrame is:

```
+-------------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+
|index              |  commonResponseText|publishedTimestamp|  commonResponseText|
+-------------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+
|                 78|Voluptatem enim a...|        1556247974|Voluptatem enim a...|
|                 87|Ut enim enim sunt...|        1558144420|Ut enim enim sunt...|
|                 99|Et est perferendi...|        1549964815|Et est perferendi...|
|                 78|Voluptatem porro ...|        1556248000|Voluptatem porro ...|
|                 87|Atque quod est au...|        1549965000|Atque quod est au...|
+-------------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+
```

I want the result to be:

```
+-------------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+
|commonResponseIndex|  index             |publishedTimestamp|  commonResponseText|
+-------------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+
|                 78|Voluptatem porro ...|        1556248000|Voluptatem porro ...|
|                 87|Atque quod est au...|        1549965000|Atque quod est au...|
+-------------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: did you try out the solution? did you find it useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
val editedDF = Seq(("A",3),("B",3)).toDF("id","timestamp")
val messageDF = Seq(("A",2),("B",2),("A",2),("A",3),("B",4),("A",2),("B",2),("c",9)).toDF("id","timestamp")
```

Finally I used this join:

```
    // Filter out the edited meesages.
    val editedFilteredDF  = messageDF.join(editedDF,
(editedDF("id") === messageDF("id")) && (editedDF("timestamp") > messageDF("timestamp")),
joinType="left_anti")
```

The result:

```
 editedFilteredDF.show()
+---+---------+
| id|timestamp|
+---+---------+
|  A|        3|
|  B|        4|
|  c|        9|
+---+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate your message table, join it with edited table and filter

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
# Test dataframe
tst=sqlContext.createDataFrame([('A',2),('B',2),('A',2),('A',3),('B',4),('A',2),('B',2),('c',9)],schema=("id","count"))
tst1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('A',4),('B',1)],schema=("id","val"))
# Aggregate and join
tst_g=tst.groupby('id').agg(F.max('count').alias('count'))
tst_j= tst_g.join(tst1,tst_g.id==tst1.id,'left')
# Filter result
tst_f = tst_j.where((F.col('count')>=F.col('val'))|(F.col('val').isNull()))
```

The result is :

```
tst_j.show()

+---+-----+----+----+
| id|count|  id| val|
+---+-----+----+----+
|  c|    9|null|null|
|  B|    4|   B|   1|
|  A|    3|   A|   4|
+---+-----+----+----+
 tst_f.show()
+---+-----+----+----+
| id|count|  id| val|
+---+-----+----+----+
|  c|    9|null|null|
|  B|    4|   B|   1|
+---+-----+----+----+
```

Finally, you can drop the irrelevant columns.

If you need the full data, then you can join the update table with message table and do the same. If the update table is small, then consider a broadcast join for performance reason.

```
# Approach to join with full table
# Test dataframe
tst=sqlContext.createDataFrame([('A',2),('B',2),('A',2),('A',3),('B',4),('A',2),('B',2),('c',9)],schema=("id","count"))
tst1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('A',4),('B',1)],schema=("id","val"))
#%%
# join with the full table
tst_j= tst.join(tst1,tst.id==tst1.id,'left')
# Filter result
tst_f = tst_j.where((F.col('count')>=F.col('val'))|(F.col('val').isNull()))
```

Hint : if you dont want two id columns in your result you can change the join syntax as tst.join(tst1,on="id",how='left')

Comment: Why does id = B and Count =2 not show up in the results? I'm not sure this is solving the problem

Comment: I have update the approach to join with full table, can you check it out.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for posting! I found a solution thats a little simpler and in scala

Comment: glad that you got help.